# iOS give users default downloadable content

Tags: iphone, ios6, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm facing this problem while designing my iOS app. Suppose that a user purchases an app and downloads it to the iPhone. I would like to provide him with a default consumable item the first time he runs the app to use whenever he wants , however I would also like to track if the user has already consumed the item. This way if he decides to reinstall the app we can restore the transactions (if he used the item) or we can avoid possible intents to download different kind of content by reinstalling app and consuming default items each time. (Guess NSUserDefaults is not an option here).

One approach that came to my mind was using UDID(or any iOS 6 alternatives) to keep a record on server of the user's device the moment he uses the default item. But this will limit items just to the device from which they consumed content.

It would be great to support all the user's devices (like inAppPurchases), but I can't figure out a way to implement this.

Any suggestions or help would be great.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have a backend web server of any kind to support this application?

Comment: Yes, in fact once the user consumes the item he will be prompted to choose the content to download from the backend server.

Answer (score 0):

In order to tie information to a user (not just a device she used at one time), you'll need to ask the user to identify herself and save it someplace other than the device.  In other words, a backend that implements registration and login.

From scratch, this can be a lot of effort that an iOS developer didn't count on.  Fortunately, there are several services in the world that provide a substantial head start.  [Here's a nice round-up](http://www.apievangelist.com/2012/08/22/mobile-backend-as-a-service-roundup-and-the-future-of-web-apis/).  I've had direct experience only with [Parse.com,](http://www.parse.com) and think it's excellent.